# NOT IN (SELECT * FROM X) equivalent for MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am building an application which will do offline matching periodically on a MongoDB collection.  What I need to do however is get a list of all potential matches that have not previously matched.

So for example, imagine the following objects (simplified to make this more readable):

`person { _id: 1, name: 'Matt', previouslyMatched: [2] }`

`person { _id: 2, name: 'John', previouslyMatched: [1] }`

`person { _id: 3, name: 'Tony', previouslyMatched: [] }`

I want to run a query on Matt (id:1) to find out if there are any other person records that are not in the previouslyMatched array.

Now in SQL I would so something like `SELECT ID FROM person WHERE ID <> 1 AND ID NOT IN (SELECT match_id from person_match where person_id = 1)`
assuming of course that I have a lookup table called person_match with the columns person_id and match_id which stores all previous matches.  I realise there are potential performance pitfalls in this query, but please bear with me as this is just an example and other optimisations will be done.

In MongoDB, it's just not clear how I would go about doing this though.  I could of course retrieve the person document (id:1), then retrieve all other people documents, and check if the ID is in the previouslyMatched array client-side, but I am concerned about the performance hit of this in regards to unnecessarily large data transfers to the client from the DB server.

I know there is a [$nin](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24nin) function, but I have read that the performance of this is not great, and once again, I'm not sure how wise an idea it is to pass in a potentially extremely long array of IDs to this field as my app scales.

My gut feeling tells me that the answer might lie in [Server side code execution](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Server-side+Code+Execution), but I'm not clear how this can be achieved.

Finally, I am also worried about how many items can be stored in a single array field practically.  Is there a practical limit?

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're trying to do a join here. It's not exactly a join, but the SQL `IN` syntax effectively allows you to apply the output from one set of data to the other.

In either case, MongoDB does not support joins and it does not support the `WHERE IN (subtable)` syntax. The `$in` syntax you mention is equivalent to `WHERE IN (a,b,c)`, with a fixed list.

The only methods I can see here involve multiple queries (2 or more) or some form of client side processing.

> My gut feeling tells me that the answer might lie in Server side code execution,...

Server-side code execution has some limitations around locking. If you want to do this query a lot I'm not confident that server-side code will effectively solve this.

> Finally, I am also worried about how many items can be stored in a single array field practically. Is there a practical limit?

A MongoDB Document can only contain 16MB of data. That's a hard physical limit.

A 64-bit integer takes [8 bytes](http://bsonspec.org/#/specification). So that's a couple million ints. It's obviously much less for strings.

My personal rule of thumb is thousands or tens of thousands (depending on the data). If you need to store *"hundreds of thousands"*, you're probably going to bump into that 16MB limit.

Comment: Thanks @gates, that is very useful.  I will work on a solution based on this and come back and post my findings when done.  One final question, any advice where I can find out more about the locking that may occur when executing server side code?

Comment: Not really well-documented right now. Here's the basic premise. Each `mongod` process has a single instance of the javascript engine. If you do that "server-side" query, you're locking that single instance. Normally MongoDB has one write lock but can do reads on multiple cores. If you're running this "stored proce", you're leveraging that one core. You're also competing with Map/Reduce or any other `eval()` call.

Answer (score 0):

You have to perform multiple queries...there is nothing like a Sub-Select in MongoDB or perform some explicit filtering on the application side.

Comment: Oh, that could become expensive in terms of I/O especially when using a hosted MongoDB.  Is there not some way of writing some javascript code that effectively does these lookups using server side code execution?  That would at least reduce the need for hundreds/thousands of requests potentially.